# How do I for loop throughout a list of dictionaries inside a tkinter label['text]?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop, tkinter

I have multiple varibles and one of them is a list of dictionaries and each dictionary has a string K and List V. I'm trying to somehow loop thought the dictionaries and return each and print it with "\n" inside the label['text'] .
E.g. of dict:

```
 results =  [{'took':['verb','past']}, {'Adam':['noun','masc']}]
```

Here is my label['text'] code:

```
Label['text'] = ("original:"+simple_string+"parsed_results:"+[token for token in str(results)])
```

When I run the code above, I get a "typeError: must be str, not list"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not everything ought to be a one liner; in this case, you should probably extract the string formatting from the making of the label; maybe in a function?

```
def prepare_text_for_label(dict_of_dict):
    formatted_strings = []
    for d in dict_of_dict:
        for k, v in d.items():
            token_string = f"[{', '.join([token for token in v])}]"
            word_string = f'original: {k}, parsed_results: {token_string}'
            formatted_strings.append(word_string)
    return '\n'.join(formatted_strings)


results =  [{'took':['verb','past']}, {'Adam':['noun','masc']}]

print(prepare_text_for_label(results))   # replaced Label with print to show the formatted text.
# Label['text'] = prepare_text_for_label(results)
```

**output:**

```
original: took, parsed_results: [verb, past]
original: Adam, parsed_results: [noun, masc]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you @Reblochon very much appreciated :)

Comment: Cool, glad I was able to help you.